# MySQL: displaying averages or null

Tags: mysql, null, average

I have two tables product and review, some products have reviews, others do not. I want to display the products and for products which have reviews I want to calculate their average rating, if a product has no reviews the average rating should be displayed as `null`.

Example:

Product:

```
| Id | Name |
| 1  | dog  |
| 2  | cat  |
```

Review:

```
| Id | Rating|
| 1  | 1     |
| 1  | 5     |
```

What should be displayed:

```
| Id | Name | Avg_rating |
| 1  | dog  | 3          |
| 2  | cat  | NULL       |
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: A LEFT JOIN and then aggregation...

Answer (score 0):

You can `left join`, aggregate and `round()`:

```
select p.id, p.name, round(avg(r.rating)) avg_rating
from product p
left join review r on r.id = p.id
group by p.id, p.name
```

Comment: I tried this solution but it only seems to give one entry and its average rating,  is there a way to output the entire table?

Comment: @pikkunen: this generates one record for each product (ie for each row in the `product` table), which is what your demonstrated in your question.